# jqGrid-cell column with hiperlink

Tags: jqgrid-formatter

I am using jqGrid to draw my table, but I want to convert a cell into a link, that is, when I hover over that cell and click I can go to show X information ... Thank you very much ...
Below is the code used so far, so you know what I am using and what I should add or change:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    url: "#{request.contextPath}/rest/selfInvitationRest/getSelfInvitationUsers?" + "taxId=" + 
          $("#frm\\:taxId").val() + "&companyName=" + $("#frm\\:companyName").val()
          + "&state=" + $("#frm\\:state").val() + "&startDate=" + $("#frm\\:startDate_input").val() + 
          "&endDate=" + $("#frm\\:endDate_input").val() + "&locale=#{languageBean.locale}&countryCode=# 
          {loginBean.country}",
    mtype: "POST",
    height: 260,   
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    formatter:linkFormat,
    colModel: [
       formatter:"{label: "#{msg['label.taxId']}", index: 'miniSiteUserPK.taxId', name: 
                   'miniSiteUserPK.taxId', sorttype: 'string', sortable: false}",...
```

Function used for "linkFormat":

```
function linkFormat(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
   return "<a href='#' onclick='$(\"#frm\\\\:gridIndex\").val(\"" + (parseInt(options.rowId) - 1) + 
   "\");$(\"#frm\\\\:userDetailRedirect\").click();'>" + cellvalue.trim() + "</a>";
}
```

Comment: I suggest you first to look at some demos and documentation on how to use the formatter. If you use Guriddo jqGrid you can look [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/) and  here the [demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I have already read that documentation, but what I have not been able to define is how to convert the cell into a link, what I can convert is the data and I already know that

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean with convert "cell to a link". What you mean with cell? Let suppose you have a very simple table with data on it. How look in this case cell to a link. Can you provide example without using jqGrid just a simple table?

Comment: Friend I explain better, I have the table: <table> <td><tr>...</tr></td> </table> what I want is to convert the cell or row into a link, that is to say something like this like this, <table> <td>
<a href="#"<tr> ... </tr> </a>
</td> </table>.
So in jqGrid what I want is to include:
  colModel: [
                       ===> {label: "# {msg ['label.taxId']}"},
] in something like this: <a> {label: "# {msg ['label.taxId']}"} </a> so that the cell or row is linked